# How to fetch latest version of a artifact from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three kind of artifacts. I store these artifacts in database with following columns:

```
artifact_type varchar2(20) not null,
artifact_version varchar2(40) not null,
artifact_blob blob default empty_blob()
```

The versions are store in following format : `3.0.0.0.0`
There is a query, where I have to return the latest version for a artifact. The max() will not return correct result for varchar. So, is there a way to find a max for this version format, or should I store version in some other way or should I create one more column which will be like latest flag.

Comment: Do NOT put in an extra column in your table. Too high risk of data inconsistency when latest version changes. (Or use triggers to ensure always valid value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the highest version for each `artifact_type` providing that you have only numbers and dots (i.e. not 3.0.2.1.1b or something).  This is for Oracle 12c

```
SELECT a.artifact_type, a.artifact_version, a.artifact_blob
FROM
    artifacts a
WHERE   a.artifact_version =
(
SELECT  b.artifact_version
FROM
    artifacts b
WHERE   b.artifact_type = a.artifact_type
ORDER
BY  CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.artifact_version,'[^.]+',1,  1) AS NUMBER) DESC,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.artifact_version,'[^.]+',1,  2) AS NUMBER) DESC,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.artifact_version,'[^.]+',1,  3) AS NUMBER) DESC,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.artifact_version,'[^.]+',1,  4) AS NUMBER) DESC,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(b.artifact_version,'[^.]+',1,  5) AS NUMBER) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
/
```

For 11g you'll need to use the rownum trick to limit the rowset in the sub-select to the first row only.

Answer (score 1):

As a common decision, you can use [user-defined aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm).

If 'last version' is equals of 'last row inserted', you can add an 'insertion date' column and use it for ordering. Sometimes other lightweight approaches can be used. For example, if you can to format version as '003.000.000.000', varchar comparision would be quite enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the version in another format.  Although you can use regular expressions to parse this, a zero-padded version number would do what you want.  Instead of 3.0.0.0.0, use 003.000.000.000.000.  This is more verbose but it allows orders and comparisons.

If you know that versions will always have four periods, then you could do a sort with something like:

```
order by cast(regexp_substr(artifact_version, '[0-9]{0.}.', 1, 1) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(artifact_version, '[0-9]{0.}.', 1, 2) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(artifact_version, '[0-9]{0.}.', 1, 3) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(artifact_version, '[0-9]{0.}.', 1, 4) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(artifact_version, '[0-9]{0.}.', 1, 5) as number)
```

And then pull the first element for the `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can Use three numeric fields, Major, Minor, Patch to store the version number. Which will be easily sort-able, but you have to get three fields.

Option 2: Put it in different table and display it as a view:

```
Table tversion (
  major NUMBER(3),
  minor NUMBER(3),
  patch NUMBER(3)
)

View vversion is 
  select major || '.' || minor || '.' || patch AS version,
         major * 1000000 + minor * 1000 + patch AS sortorder from tversion;
```

Option 3: Keep your database schema as is and put your logic in client side to get max version.